# spectrum of commutative monoids

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My professor mentioned that the construction of spectrum of commutative rings can be generalized to that of commutative monoids, and several propositions in chapter 2 of Hartshorne's algebraic algebra can be analogously generalized to the spectrum of monoids. To name a few, Proposition II 2.2, Proposition II 2.3 and Theorem II 3.3.

The question is what are these analogous propositions look like in detail, can we directly change the proofs into the case of schemes of monoids? Is there any proposition in chapter 2 that cannot be generalized?

Answer (score 0):

This is closely related to the study of $\mathbb{F}_1$-schemes. In [this paper by Oliver Lorscheid and Matt Szczesny](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.05233.pdf) they talk about the construction of projective monoid schemes $\operatorname{MProj}$ and the notion of quasicoherent sheaves over them. If you read the introduction you'll find the references to the origins of these ideas where you can probably find the results you mention and more.